# Django Rest Framework override model fields in modelserialzer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Let's say I have this serializer:

```
class DashboardItemSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    offer = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    cart_item = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    stock_details = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = OrderItem
        fields = ('uuid', 'seller', 'total', 'tax', 'offer', 'shipping_address', 'cart_item', 'stock_details')

    def offer(self, obj):
        return 123

    def cart_item(self, obj):
        return 123

    def stock_details(self, obj):
        return 123
```

these fields `offer`, `cart_item` and `stock_details` are model fields, and I would like to override it with to return different values, but looks like DRF ignores the customized fields and return the original value in obj.

If I don't put them in the `fields` list, the data will simply not include those fields.

```
class DashboardItemSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    offer = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    cart_item = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    stock_details = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = OrderItem
        fields = ('uuid', 'seller', 'total', 'tax', 'shipping_address')

    def offer(self, obj):
        return 123

    def cart_item(self, obj):
        return 123

    def stock_details(self, obj):
        return 123
```

One way to do it is to [define fields explicitly](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-fields-explicitly), but I wonder if there is a easier way.

Comment: why do you mean with `if I don't put them in the fields list, the data will simply not include those fields.`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You forgot to add `get_` prefix. Your methods names should have `get_` prefix as it is mentioned in [SerializerMethodField docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield)

```
def get_offer(self, obj):
    return 123

def get_cart_item(self, obj):
    return 123

def get_stock_details(self, obj):
    return 123
```

Answer (score 4):

It is also possible to pass the method name as an optional parameter to each `serializers.SerializerMethodField()` and specify the custom method name you want to use for each custom/overridden field. This way you can omit the `get_` prefix in the resolver method names inside the serializer class.